# Swapping two pointers to char in c++ by real call by reference

Tags: c++

I am trying to swap two points on const char with real call-by-reference. But I have problems.

```
void swap(const char *&str1, const char *&str2) { //swap char pointers
    const char *one = str1;
    str1 = str2;
    str2 = one;
}

int main(void){
    const char *str1 = "Apple";
    const char *str2 = "Potato";
    swap(*str1, *str2);
    return 0.0;
}
```

I keep on getting this error:

> invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char'

Comment: still get the same error

Comment: @user2678614: No, you don't.

Comment: `return 0.0;` is valid, but insane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be dereferences the pointers when calling `swap`. You need to call:

```
swap(str1, str2);
```

Or, better still, use [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Also, if you're trying to run the code you've written they you'll need to either prototype `swap` or swap the functions around:

```
void swap(const char *&str1, const char *&str2) 
{ 
  const char *one = str1;
  str1 = str2;
  str2 = one;
}    

int main(void)
{
  const char *str1 = "Apple";
  const char *str2 = "Potato";
  swap(str1, str2);

  return 0;
}
```

Also, `main` returns an int, not a float

Comment: i changed that, thank you. But still I have the same problem.

Comment: Also just use `std::swap()` (in `<utility>`) instead of writing your own swap function. That's what it's there for.

Comment: this was the assignment given (to make the swap function), so I cannot do it directly. Can you help me with any error you see?

Comment: @user2678614 - I've added to the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. Now its just fine :) 
About the float return of main, that was by mistake that I kept it here. 
I removed the '*' while calling swap and edited the function content as you suggested and it works just splendid :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) (located in either the `<algorithm>` or `<utility>` header) instead of rolling your own:

```
std::swap(str1, str2);
```

Also, you should consider using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of `const char*` in general:

```
std::string str1 = "Apple";
std::string str2 = "Potato";
```

of course the `std::swap` algorithm will still work just fine.

And finally, neither `void` in the argument list of `main` nor `return 0.0` are necessary in C++.

Here's the code revisited with the advices above:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str1 = "Apple";
    std::string str2 = "Potato";
    std::swap(str1, str2);
}
```

and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3c21c77328595b5)'s the live example.

---

In response to Mr. [Cthulhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2195721/cthulhu) down here, I'll try to answer the question more explicitly.

Your error is caused by the fact that by dereferencing the pointers of type `const char*` you are actually getting an expression of type `const char&` which is obviously incompatible with the type expressed in your `swap` function. Here's the correct call to the function:

```
swap(str1, str2);
```

But the again, why replicating the code of `std::swap`? (this is a rhetorical question, in case you were wondering wether to flag this as "not an answer")

Comment: Now that's something new. Who's to say me I cannot create my own function if it's functional equivalent already exist in some library? Doesn't answer original question anyway.

Comment: @Cthulhu, The programming principle DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) says it. You might not be familiar with the concept.

Comment: @Cthulhu: All experts. It's nothing "new" at all.

Comment: @Jefffrey sorry, didn't realize it was you who wrote `std::swap`.

Comment: @Cthulhu, what difference does it make who wrote it?

Comment: Well, word `yourself` kinda stands for it. But then, you might not be familiar with it.

Comment: @Cthulhu: You shouldn't because the guys who designed and implemented the stdlib are probably way smarter than you and had to spend way more time on it than you can afford to spend on it and why waste your own time duplicating their work?

Comment: @Cthulhu, You really don't get it, do you?

Comment: So I suppose you never spent time in school/university proving theorems etc. Why bother when it's already proved by people way smarter then you? It's the same, topic starter was writing the function to better learn the language.

Comment: @Cthulhu: If it's an exercise then that's different. You never said that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well the thought that topic starter was already working on some serious application while having such questions never visited my mind, sorry.

Comment: @Cthulhu: It happens on SO _all the time_.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `swap()` *after* you're calling it. In C++, functions should be defined before they are called. Move the definition of `swap()` to the top of the file, above `main()`. You will then get this error:

```
test.cpp:11: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
```

Your `main()` function should return `0` (an `int`), not `0.0` which is a `double`.

Fixing this, you'll finally get this error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const char*&’ from expression of type ‘const char’
test.cpp:1: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void swap(const char*&, const char*&)’
```

This is because you're dereferencing your arguments to `swap()`. Remove the `*` and the program now works fine.

**However**, you should simply remove your `swap()` function altogether, `#include <utility>`, and use `std::swap()`.